# Get list of users that uses one endpoint using Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Scenario:

Elastic search

Backend that send a log row to elastic each time that one user uses the endpoint (with the field event.user_id filled with the value of the user)

Now I want to use Kibana or postman to get a list of event.user_id but with no values repeated (I prefer to use kibana to give the dashboard to not technical users).

I want to get:

```
event.user_id
-------------
john.smith
barbie.ch
pedro.gonzalez
...
```

Comment: use terms agrgegation

Answer (score 0):

By using [Collapse](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html) or [Terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) you can get distinct values.

```
{
  "collapse": {
    "field": "event.user_id.keyword"
  }
}
```

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "unique-users": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "event.user_id.keyword",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```